# How would I write this NSSet test using an NSPredicate?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nspredicate, nsset

Hi I create a common set using NSSet's objectsPassingTest method. Is there a way I could write this using an NSPredicate? I want more the test to match on more than just seeing if one set contains an object.

```
NSSet *commonMusic = [userMusicTitles objectsPassingTest:^BOOL(id obj, BOOL *stop) {
    return [friendMusicTitles containsObject:obj];
}];
```

The two sets contain NSStrings, and I'd like to use something such as

If userMusicTitles.title LIKE[cd] friendMusicTitles.title

Thanks!

Comment: If `userMusicTitles` is a set of strings, what is `userMusicTitles.title` ? Can you explain more what kind of objects the sets contain and what the intended results is?

Comment: Yes, they are strings. I want to see if each string in friendMusicTitles is also in userMusicTitles, and create a set containing common titles. But I want the comparison to be a little fuzzier than a strict stringIsEqual or contains object, hence the LIKE and [cd] requirements.

Comment: I still don't understand how the strings should be compared. What is "a little fuzzier"? Can you give concrete examples?

Comment: Sure: TitleA would equal "titlea" and "titlea remix". NSPredicate can even use regular expressions.

Comment: So you want to check if a title from the first set is a *substring* of a title from the second set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get you correctly you want to create a new NSSet that contain all element that are common to 2 different NSSet.

```
- (void)testTest
{
NSArray *a = @[ @"boris", @"bob", @"claire", @"x" ];
NSArray *b = @[ @"Boris", @"BOB", @"vince", @"y", @"x" ];
NSSet *userMusicTitles = [NSSet setWithArray:a];
NSSet *friendMusicTitles = [NSSet setWithArray:b];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF LIKE[cd] $STR"];
__block NSPredicate *blockPredicate = nil;
NSSet *commonMusic = [userMusicTitles objectsPassingTest:^BOOL(NSString *obj, BOOL *stop) {
    blockPredicate = [predicate predicateWithSubstitutionVariables:@{ @"STR" : obj }];
    return ([friendMusicTitles filteredSetUsingPredicate:blockPredicate].count > 0);
}];

NSLog(@"common music == %@", commonMusic);
}
```

Other option.

[NSMutableSet](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableSet_Class/Reference/NSMutableSet.html) have the `- (void)intersectSet:(NSSet *)otherSet` method. But it won't do the `LIKE[cd]`. You would have to store your NSString already in [cd] form.

Other option would be to loop throughout one set and use the value in a predicate then add the result to a NSMutableSet that at the end would contain your elements.

Comment: I would not use `LIKE` because that interprets "*" and "?" as wildcard characters. Perhaps better `=[cd]` or `CONTAINS[cd]`.

Comment: @JasonC.Howlin Thank you. It was interesting, I've learn the SELF thing in the predicate while looking into this problem.

Comment: @MartinR For performance it would be better to have the string already in a [cd] form, the [cd] is the more expensive part. (from what I've read, but never tested it myself... so I could be wrong)

Comment: @VinceBurn: Yes, you are right. My comment was more about "LIKE", which is for wildcard comparisons such as "LIKE '*abc?'".

Comment: @VinceBurn: Another small remark: If you declare `blockPredicate` inside the block then you don't need the `__block` modifier`.

Comment: Martin, thanks also. In this case CONTAINS[cd] does work better for my purposes.

Comment: @MartinR You can do that for the __block thing, I just didn't wanted to have that piece of memory assign and destroyed at every execution of the block. I'm not sure what is best here, having a space reserve on the Heap for blockPredicate or reclaim a space for it every time the block is running?